# MySQL запрос по фильтрам

Tags: поиск, php, фильтры, select, mysql

Есть таблица связей между товарами и фильтрами:

`id`, `tovar_id`, `filter_id`

Пользователь чекает, например, три фильтра: 1, 2, 3. 
Надо вывести список `tovar_id`, у которого есть связь с каждым из этих фильтров.

Мой вариант такой:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`t0`.`tovar_id`) FROM `link` AS `t0`, `link` AS `t1`, link AS `t2` WHERE `t0`.`filter_id`=1 AND `t1`.`tovar_id`=`t0`.`tovar_id` AND `t1`.`filter_id`=2 AND `t2`.`tovar_id`=`t1`.`tovar_id` AND `t2`.`filter_id`=3;
```

Но я не уверен, что он правильный. Потому, что если отметить 70 фильтров, то могут возникнуть трудности..

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это верный способ положить БД, имхо. У Вас на каждый фильтр добавляется +1 джоин. Возможно, вот такой запрос, будет эффективнее, хотя тоже не факт. Нужно смотреть на конкретных данных, какие планы запросов получаются и т.д.

```
select tmp.tovar_id
from
  (select tovar_id
        , count(filter_id) as check_sum
   from link
   where filter_id in (1, 2, 3)
   group by tovar_id) as tmp
where check_sum = &filter_count
```

, где `filter_count` - количество выбранных фильтров

PS
В комментариях подсказали еще один вариант, что-то я про него не подумал, хотя смысл точно такой же

```
select tovar_id
     , count(filter_id)
from link
where filter_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by tovar_id
having count(filter_id) = &filter_count
```

Comment: Так у Вас же не учитывается, какие именно фильтры пользователь выбрал?

Comment: Точнее, не учитывается то что выбраться должны только товары имеющие все три фильтра.
На схожем ресурсе, уточняют что можно использовать HAVING COUNT(*)=3..

Comment: Как раз-таки учитывется. Во вложенном запросе мы выбираем все товары, у которых имеются любой из отправленных фильтров, а во внешнем берем как раз те, которые имеют только ВСЕ нужные фильтры (работает только в случае, если один фильтр можно привязать к  товару только один раз, что на мой взгляд логично)

Comment: Лично у меня запрос не работает, как ожидалось. 
Похоже что, выбираются связи по товару, которые имеют либо тот либо другой фильтр и имеют по-три связи в этой таблице..

Comment: хм, вот пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58e69/3.0 Всё работает, если у вас один и тот же фильтр, конечно, не привязан к товару несколько раз

Comment: Похоже что мой косяк. У меня в таблице еще есть связь по категории и получается что товар может быть привязан к одному фильтру по разным категориям. В таком случае в having пишем: count(distinct filter_id)=3