# Посчитать количество строк по сложному MySQL запросу

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!

Мой первый вопрос по данной теме был тут: [MySQL запрос по фильтрам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/217751).

Тогда ответом был следующий запрос:

```
SELECT `gid`
FROM `link`
WHERE `fid` in (1, 2, 4, 5)
GROUP BY gid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `fid`) = 4.
```

Теперь встал новый вопрос: **как посчитать количество таких строк, не выбирая их все?**

Comment: не выбирать совсем не получится, т.к. этот запрос предполагает выборку всех, но в рамках mysql можно остаться примерно так:

    SELECT count(*) FROM (
        SELECT `gid`
        FROM `link`
        WHERE `fid` in (1, 2, 4, 5)
        GROUP BY gid
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `fid`) = 4
      )

Comment: забыл 

    FROM (SELECT ...) as t

Comment: @zb' пожалуйста, добавьте ваши комментарии ответом

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев от [zb'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11304/zb)*

Не выбирать совсем не получится, т.к. этот запрос предполагает выборку всех, но в рамках mysql можно поступить примерно так:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  (SELECT
     gid
   FROM
     link
   WHERE
     fid in (1, 2, 4, 5)
   GROUP BY
     gid
   HAVING
      COUNT(DISTINCT fid) = 4
  )
```

Comment: я надеюсь, @zb' может сам добавить ответ

Comment: Не могу,  это было дваигода назад,  я даже mysql забыть успел.